# Discord.js Button Links

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hello I am trying to use a discord.js button to link to a website

This is what I attempted to do

```
const row = new MessageActionRow()
.addComponents(
new MessageButton()
    .setCustomId('whatever')
    .setLabel('CLICK THIS')
    .setLink("google.com")
    .setStyle('LINK'),
);
```

However this does not work due to set link not being a function

And the documentation doesnt help me out with this

Comment: Is it not `setURL` instead? https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageButton

Answer (score 5):

Conor Reid is right

```
const row = new MessageActionRow()
.addComponents(
new MessageButton()
    .setLabel('CLICK THIS')
    .setURL("urlhere")
    .setStyle('LINK'),
);
```

The correct function is setUrl()

Comment: Discord JS has been Updated to v14 now. Make sure when doing `.setStyle()` you do `.setStyle(ButtonStyle.Link)`.

Answer (score 2):

`MessageButton.setLink()` is not a function. Although I can see why this may be confusing because of the `setStyle('LINK')` being required. The correct function is `.setURL(url)`. The MessageButton documentation is available here https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageButton

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setURL` instead of `setLink`

It is in the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageButton)

```js
let url 'https://google.com'
const row = new MessageActionRow()
.addComponents(
new MessageButton()
    .setLabel('Google')
    .setURL(url)
    .setStyle('LINK')
);
```